# Eccentric keepers

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, word-property

*There are four keepers in our fantastic creatures preserve who have certain preferences in the kinds of creatures they care for. Can you figure out what kind of creature is arriving soon?*

> **Colleen**
>
> - likes griffins but dislikes sphinxes,
> - likes chinchillas but dislikes gerbils,
> - likes karkadanns but dislikes unicorns,
> - likes llamas but dislikes antelopes,
> - likes crocottas but dislikes hyenas,
> - and positively adores raccoons!

> **Bancroft**
>
> - likes peahens but dislikes peacocks,
> - likes sphinxes but dislikes griffins,
> - likes gazelles but dislikes antelopes,
> - likes basilisks but dislikes cockatrices,
> - likes iguanas but dislikes lizards,
> - and positively despises coots!

> **Felix**
>
> - likes sphinxes but dislikes harpies,
> - likes leopards but dislikes camelopards,
> - likes ammits but dislikes hippos,
> - likes tigers but dislikes zebras,
> - likes griffins but dislikes eagles.

> **Avi**
>
> - likes pegasi but dislikes unicorns,
> - likes bats but dislikes mice,
> - likes griffins but dislikes sphinxes,
> - likes herons but dislikes ostriches,
> - likes cockatrices but dislikes snakes.

[image]

Comment: You haven't fully specified the question that is to be answered in the puzzle description. "Can you figure out what kind of creature is arriving soon?" Is the puzzle to find a creature that all 4 keepers like? And is there any reason the choices are arranged in a grid?

Comment: I guess there is a bit of an enigmatic puzzle going on here as well... Yes, there is a very good reason for the creatures to be arranged in a grid.

Comment: Is the case for all examples listed in the puzzle that, e.g., if Colleen likes griffins (plural), she also likes a griffin (singular)? Or are there perhaps some cases where a keeper likes a plural without liking the corresponding singular, or vice versa?

Comment: @thecommexokid Keepers typically like singulars and plurals in equal measure. there might be exceptions if plurals are formed in weird ways, but I can't come up with an example off the top of my head.

Comment: It didn't keep me from figuring out the relevant keeper, but *geese* and *calves* come to mind.

Comment: @thecommexokid Ah, missed that - English is not my first language so exceptions like this are harder for me to catch :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Colleen likes

> Animals with doubled letters (like her own name), this includes Ferret, Banshee, Niffler, Allocamelus, Cabbit, Hippocamp, and Moose; yielding the letter C

Bancroft hates

> Half his name, the letters c, r, o, f, and t are verboten. This leaves Yak, Bunyip, Skunk, Banshee, Kelpie, Guinea Pig, Lamia, and Weasel; yielding the letter O.

Felix likes

> Kitties! Whole or in parts, including the Merlion, Panther, Caracal, Manticore, and Cabbit; yielding the letter L

Avi likes

> Fliers, as the name implies. These include the Thestral, Owl, Harpy, Dragon, Phoenix, and sometimes Manticore; either way, this yields a T

So the animal that is next to arrive:

> Colt

Comment: Almost there - you still need to figure out what are Bancroft's preferences

Comment: @Sconibulus, I cracked Colleen and Bancroft, but had no idea for Felix or Avi. If you'd like a (slight) hint to help with Bancroft, I'll offer that rot13(uvf anzr vf gur zbfg eryrinag bs nyy sbhe xrrcref).

Comment: @thecommexokid - you can also post your answer for Bancroft separately and enjoy well-deserved upvotes :-)